# rails minitest bdd how to specify which test superclass to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Using a Grape API and add the tests in the `Rakefile`. Its a Rack application mounted on the main rails app.

```
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(:api) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/api/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end

Rake::Task[:test].enhance [ 'test:api' ]
```

However if I try to test it there aren't any of the controller methods.

```
describe API do
  # get, post, patch etc all raise
end
```

Error below.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<#<Class:0x007fd63cdfc0e0>:0x007fd63cdc7a70>
```

How can I test rack apps with `minitest-rails` bdd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
class MiniTest::Spec
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    API
  end
end
```